# Opening Realm file in browser always requires an encryption key and I want alternative

Tags: arrays, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

When I tried to open a Realm file using Realm Browser it tells that I have to enter a key
How can I open them or get that key ?

I've tried to read old answers but with no help , and I have some issues by dealing with MongoDB docs and I find it complex :(

Comment: Is the Realm File [encrypted](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/realm-files/encrypt-a-realm/)?